# Is there a shorter way to join an array to one string besides Array.prototype.join()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, join

I want to join an array to one string. Normally I would write:

```
x=a=>a.join('')

x([1,2,3,4,5]);         // '12345'
x(['a','b','c','d']);   // 'abcd'
x(['1','2']);           // '12'
x([undefined,null]);    // ''
```

Is there any way to write this function using even less characters?

Comment: Why would you possibly want something that is shorter than 8-9 characters

Comment: Probably better suited for -> https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @adeneo It's a puzzle.

Comment: Can't think of anything bitwise, using anything like `toString`, then removing commas, would be a lot longer. You really can't beat the 4 characters of `join`

Comment: Are you allowed to change Array.prototype ? And then just call [].x() to retrieve the result ?

Comment: @marvel308 - not sure, but think that having a large function sorta defeats the point, even if it's added to a native prototype

Comment: Link to the puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of ES6's template literal, you can write it like this:

```
x=a=>a.join``
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to use the default `,` delimiter:

```
x=a=>a+''
```

Comment: That doesn’t have the same result… and `x=String` is shorter.

Comment: True, 1 char shorter! And I assume no delineator is important as its an extra character that the OP could have omitted otherwise.